# Display data from back-end into formGroup Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I do have a JSON file which comes from back-end. I am using the `formGroup` in template for better handling the errors. But I am not able to see data in my array.
The issue is that the data are not populating.

Info: in the `console.log` there are data.

Does someone has idea which is the best way to do it? This is my code

```
public carrier$: Observable<Carrier>;

ngOnInit() {
 this.carrier$ = this.dataService.getCareer().pipe(
  tap(carrier => this.form.patchValue(carrier)));
}

createForm() {
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  firstDate: "",
  endDate: "",
  company: "",
  description: "",
});
```

}

And this is the Template.

```
<form *ngIf="carrier$ | async;" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="col row justify-content-left">
  <div id="personalData" class="col-md-4 text-right tLine flex-column">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-left flex-column">
    <h5>Studium / Ausbildung</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
  <div *ngFor="let carrier of carrier$ | async; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    {{carrier}}
  <div class="col row justify-content-left"  [ngClass]="{ 'isActive': toggle}" (click)="edit()">
  <div class="col-md-2 text-right flex-column">
      <input type="number" formControlName="firstDate" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 text-right flex-column">
    <input type="number" formControlName="endDate"  class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 text-left flex-column">
    <input type="text" formControlName="company" class="form-control" placeholder="your company name">
    <textarea rows="1" formControlName="description" class="form-control" placeholder="your description"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="w-100"></div>
    <div *ngIf="toggle">
      <ul>
        <li class="fa fa-trash"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-copy"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-plus-square"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!form.valid">Update</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the exact issue? is form not displaying? or even form is displaying but the data is not populating?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Form is displaying but the data is not populating.

Comment: Where are you calling createForm()

Comment: In the constructor, I will update my code.

Comment: @MohitHarshan I released that I don't need the method createForm(), I have deleted.